# Which bag is preferred in which situations?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

"The bag" can be either "el bolso" or "la bolsa" - is one preferred, or more common, than the other?

Is it that one is used in some circumstances, and the other in others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

English *purse*, Spanish *bolsa*, and French *bourse* all derive from Latin *bursa*. Just as there are many kinds of bag or sack, so too are there many kinds of *[bolsa](http://dle.rae.es/bolsa)* and *[bolso](http://dle.rae.es/bolso)*.

For the most part, *bolsa* indicates a larger thing, such as the large shopping bags you take groceries home in, whereas *bolso* indicates a smaller handbag, pocketbook, or purse — or the smaller plastic bags at the supermarket.  A *bolsa* can also be a bourse or stock exchange, while a *bolsillo* is normally the pocket of a garment.

In certain regions all this can be switched around.  For example, in Mexico a *bolsa* is the pocket of your trousers where you stick change or your billfold or any other pocket on your clothing, whereas normally this is a *bolsillo*.

*Bolsa* is also a more general word used for various sorts of sacks and expressions, including medical terms.  *Tener algo como en la bursa* is to have something in the bag, to have it all sewn up.